Username details too far from circle avatar
I am doing a widget that appears on the home screen and I don't understand why the text under the circle avatar is soo down and far . I want it under it but not this far ... any idea what I should change?  the outcome photo is this  I changed the padding but it doesn't effect the interior of the widget
 child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                    spreadRadius: 5,
                                    blurRadius: 7,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 3),
                                  )
                                ]),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.2,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                                      child: CircleAvatar(
                                        radius: 50,
                                        backgroundImage: ((snaps.data?.data()
                                                    as Map)['avatarUrl'] ==
                                                'default')
                                            ? const NetworkImage(
                                                "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png"

                                                //  activity.imageUrl,

                                                )
                                            : NetworkImage((snaps.data?.data()
                                                as Map)['avatarUrl']),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    height: 170.0,
                                    // width: double.infinity,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                    ),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                          5.0, 50.0, 5.0, 5.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width *
                                                0.5,
                                            child: SizedBox(
                                              width: 120.0,
                                              child: Center(
                                                child: Text(
                                                  (snaps.data?.data()
                                                      as Map)['name'],
                                                  // activity.name,
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                  ),
                                                  overflow:
                                                      TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                  maxLines: 2,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width *
                                                0.5,
                                            child: SizedBox(
                                              width: 120.0,
                                              child: Center(
                                                child: Text(
                                                  (snaps.data?.data()
                                                      as Map)['address'],
                                                  // activity.name,
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                  ),
                                                  overflow:
                                                      TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                  maxLines: 2,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            (snapshot2.data?.data()
                                                as Map)['category'],
                                            // activity.type,
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.grey,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          right: 35,
                          child: TextButton(
                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                              disabledBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            onPressed: null,
                            child: Text(
                              'TOP 5',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),


What do you exact want?

You have given top padding 50 in you container with height = 70.
Edit top padding to 5.0...
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
5.0)
